# how to set delete buttons in each item of a list view in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have list view. I need to set delete button to each row. Is there any standard way to
do this in android?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Android way is to not have a delete button but an action based on long press. So when you long press on the list it will show a list of stuff you can do and include delete in it. For example, you can check your Gmail, sms and long press on the thread to get this option.

Comment: May be this is helpful; http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/

Comment: @rwe: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tiny tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own list view item layout, which includes a delete button, see [here for some details on that](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/).  In the button XMl you need to have the android:onclick attribute set, then in your code have an appropiate matching method.  for example

```
<button android:onclick="deleteItem" android:text="Delete" ...>

public void deleteItem(View view) {
    ... code to delete...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do xml file with single row (with button) then make class which extends some Adapter for example:

arrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.news_row, newsList)
where MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter, news_row is xml with view of single row, newsList is ArrayList with data